# Translation of “Leave of absence”

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be the canonical or idiomatic translation of a legal term [*leave of absence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_of_absence)?

Leave of absence is when you must be away from the job, but is still considered an employee. It can be either paid or unpaid.

I have considered *foresto el ofico*, but it just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Esperanto. The Aggressor Language*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GtqEAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22leave+of+absence%22+esperanto) and [John C. Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Wells)'s [*English–Esperanto–English Dictionary*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f0Zunqj2fa0C&pg=PA43&dq=leave+of+absence+esperanto) both translate ‘leave of absence’ as *forpermeso*.

Comment: Besides the [2nd definition in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#forpermeso), the Spanish-Esperanto Dictionary by Fernando de Diego also offers the same translation with the following example: _pedir la excedencia por un año_ [to request a one-year leave of absence] → _peti unujaran forpermeson_.

Comment: Yes. It is a case of general consensus. Every source I could consult agrees.